# Why is fscanf reading 0?

Tags: c, file, io, std, scanf

I am making a simple program that can read a file line by file. Each line of the file is in the format: integer, integer, character. For example, with a file that looks like:

```
1 2 A
2 3 B
```

The expected output from the program should be:

```
1 2 A
2 3 B
```

But it is printing

```
0 2 A
0 3 B
```

How can I fix it?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>    

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    char str[1];
    int key;
    int val;

    while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %s\n", &key, &val, str) != EOF) {

        printf("Read Integer %d \n", key );
        printf("Read Integer %d \n", val );
        printf("Read String %s \n", str );
    }


   fclose(file);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: You read two integers, so you need a format such as `"%d %d"`...

Comment: You're overwriting your `str` array.  Even if only a single character is entered, two will be written (the character, followed by a null byte).  And of course, if more than one character is entered, it's even worse.  As it stands, you are subject to undefined behavior, so all bets are off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `str` as `char [1]` which is wrong.

You need to allocate a larger `str` to accommodate `'\0'`. Changing declaration as below should fix the problem.

```
char str[2];  /* Or may be larger */
/*       ^    */
```

Also it would be a good idea to remove `'\n'` from format string of `scanf` as:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %s", &key, &val, str) == 3)
/*                           ^                   ^^^^  */
```

Comment: @Pippi Don't change the question drastically in between, it makes the existing answers invalid. Instead ask a new question. Or even better, always proofread your question and ensure the code snippet reproduces the issue.

Comment: sorry about that. will do.

Answer (score 2):

You need a bigger string, you need to check `argc` value and you need a better format for your `fscanf()`. Also better to check `fscanf()` return is 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 500
#define XSTR(n) STR(n)
#define STR(n) #n

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "I need one argument.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    char str[N + 1];
    int key;
    int val;

    // "%d %d %" XSTR(N) "s" expands as "%d %d %500s"
    while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %" XSTR(N) "s", &key, &val, str) == 3)
    {

        printf("Read Integer %d \n", key );
        printf("Read Integer %d \n", val );
        printf("Read String %s \n", str );
    }


   fclose(file);

   return(0);
}
```

Edit: I added macros so that format is updated when changing N.